# The results are different from the VS code when using AWS lambda.(selenium,BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, aws-lambda, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use AWS Lambda for getting data.
(http://www.cell2gps.com/ )
So, i made a code in VS code and there is no issue.
But, when i use AWS Lambda, the result are differnt from VS code.

it is a code for VS code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("headless")
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--single-process')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('[path]/chromedriver.exe',options=options)
#driver = webdriver.Chrome('path',options=options)

driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)
driver.get('http://www.cell2gps.com/')

html=driver.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
t_list2=soup.select_one('body > center > center > script:nth-child(12)')
data=str(t_list2)
print(data)
print('--------------------------')

#driver.find_element_by_name('mcc').clear()
#driver.find_element_by_name('mcc').send_keys('@@')
#driver.find_element_by_name('mnc').clear()
#driver.find_element_by_name('mnc').send_keys('@@')
#driver.find_element_by_name('lac').clear()
#driver.find_element_by_name('lac').send_keys('@@')
#driver.find_element_by_name('cellid').clear()
#driver.find_element_by_name('cellid').send_keys('@@')
driver.find_element_by_class_name('g-recaptcha').click()
time.sleep(10)

html=driver.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
t_list2=soup.select_one('body > center > center > script:nth-child(12)')
data=str(t_list2)
print(data)

driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

the result is as below

```
<script>
var point = new mapboxgl.LngLat(-122.078643,37.422161);
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoid2FuZ3dkIiwiYSI6ImNrNjJvdTBjcjBncm4za3FuaHhod3I5Ym8ifQ.BXm0oZg7ZfoFqlsT9IlAAQ';
map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map',
center: point,
zoom: 4,
style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11'
});

map.on('load', function() {

});
</script>
--------------------------
<script>
var point = new mapboxgl.LngLat(-122.065285,37.397690);
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoid2FuZ3dkIiwiYSI6ImNrNjJvdTBjcjBncm4za3FuaHhod3I5Ym8ifQ.BXm0oZg7ZfoFqlsT9IlAAQ';
map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map',
center: point,
zoom: 14,
style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11'
});
...
map.on('load', function() {
createPoint(1,37.397690,-122.065285,700,"GSM CellTower 310-260-328-29021 location is (37.397690,-122.065285) Accuracy:700 m",0,0,18);
});
</script>
```

it is a code for AWS Lambda

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--single-process')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.binary_location = "/opt/headless/python/bin/headless-chromium"
    driver= webdriver.Chrome("/opt/headless/python/bin/chromedriver",chrome_options=options)
    driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)

    driver.get('http://www.cell2gps.com/')

    html=driver.page_source
    soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
    t_list2=soup.select_one('body > center > center > script:nth-child(12)')
    data=str(t_list2)
    print(data)
    print('--------------------------')

    #driver.find_element_by_name('mcc').clear()
    #driver.find_element_by_name('mcc').send_keys('@@')
    #driver.find_element_by_name('mnc').clear()
    #driver.find_element_by_name('mnc').send_keys('@@')
    #driver.find_element_by_name('lac').clear()
    #driver.find_element_by_name('lac').send_keys('@@')
    #driver.find_element_by_name('cellid').clear()
    #driver.find_element_by_name('cellid').send_keys('@@')
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('g-recaptcha').click()
    time.sleep(6)  #second
    
    html=driver.page_source
    soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
    t_list2=soup.select_one('body > center > center > script:nth-child(12)')
    data=str(t_list2)
    print(data)

    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
    return 0
```

```
the result is as below
<script>
var point = new mapboxgl.LngLat(-122.078643,37.422161);
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoid2FuZ3dkIiwiYSI6ImNrNjJvdTBjcjBncm4za3FuaHhod3I5Ym8ifQ.BXm0oZg7ZfoFqlsT9IlAAQ';
map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map',
center: point,
zoom: 4,
style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11'
});
map.on('load', function() {
});
</script>
--------------------------
None
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrxeq.jpg)

There is no problem in VS Code, but in AWS lambda , the data is none after click 'g-recaptcha' button.

i want to get data(t_list2=soup.select_one('body > center > center > script:nth-child(12)')) in AWS Lambda as VS code

Comment: you have used a different `time.sleep` time in each code.

Comment: also, the issue is with `('g-recaptcha').click()` so you can reduce the code:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you for comment.
"time.sleep" is different. but i also tired test with others time.But, it was the same.